# window pop up duplicated when click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $("ul.social").hide();
       $("span.link").each(function(i){
         $(this).mouseover(function(){
           $("ul.social").eq(i).show("fast", function(){
             $("ul.social li a").click(function(){
               var link = this.href;
               window.open(link, " ", "height=350,width=600");
             });
           });
         });
       });
     });
```

And this HTML :

```
<ul class="social">
    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Compartilhar <?php the_title(); ?> no LinkedIn" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/in.png" alt="" width="24" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Compartilhar <?php the_title(); ?> no Google Plus" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/gp.png" alt="" width="24" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Compartilhar <?php the_title(); ?> no Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/fb.png" alt="" width="24" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>&amp;text=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;via=chocoladesign" title="Compartilhar <?php the_title(); ?> no Twitter" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/tw.png" alt="" width="24" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

But, whenever i click on `(ul.social li a)`, he's duplicate the window. one of these opens at size `600x350` and the other opens full screen.

Why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont attach click event inside moseover event , u will get duplicated click event every time you mose over.

and `$("ul.social li a").click` is wrong , you are attaching a click to every link and not just `$("ul.social").eq(i)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.social li a").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = this.href;
        window.open(link, " ", "height=350,width=600");
     });
       $("ul.social").hide();
       $("span.link").each(function(i){
         $(this).mouseover(function(){
           $("ul.social").eq(i).show("fast", function(){

           });
         });
       });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you click on that link, it is doing the default action of opening the link, like it normally would, and then it's opening it again with your window.open code. So just add event.preventDefault() so that it stops the first opening from happening.

```
 $("ul.social li a").click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               var link = this.href;
               window.open(link, " ", "height=350,width=600");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because, the default action of `<a>` is not prevented, due to which even after opening the popup, the link opens in a new tab.

Try this.

```
 $("ul.social li a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var link = this.href;
   window.open(link, " ", "height=350,width=600");
 });
```

For further info, refer [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)